# Why doesn't Intellij python typing complain when a string is passed instead of an object?

Tags: python, python-typing

While debugging a package, I discovered python code like this -

```
# file1.py
class XYZ:
    SOME_CLASS_CONSTANT = "some_string"
    ...         
    # rest of the class

# file2.py
class PQR:
    my_dict: dict[int, XYZ] = {
        1 : XYZ.SOME_CLASS_CONSTANT
    }
    ...
    # rest of the class
```

My question -
`my_dict` should take key-value pairs that are `<int, XYZ>`. But `XYZ.SOME_CLASS_CONSTANT` is of type `str` (not `XYZ`).

Why doesn't my IDE complain about this?

Comment: PS - Please redirect me if this a duplicate. Couldn't find it myself.

Comment: What IDE are you using? `mypy` correctly rejects the assignment (assuming `file2.py` uses `from file1 import XYZ`; otherwise, you'd get an error that `XYZ` is undefined)

Comment: *If* the type of `XYZ.SOME_CLASS_CONSTANT` is being inferred as `Any`, rather than `str`, for some reason, then there is no typing error, because `Any` is compatible with any type (including `XYZ`).

Comment: (Sorry, I missed Intellij was mentioned in the title. I guess the question is, what does Intellij use for type checking? `mypy`, some other 3rd-party tool, its own implementation of a type checker?)

Comment: @chepner An update - my_dict is another class variable of another class. My IDE is flagging a direct variable but not a class variable.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a dict type hint is `dict[key, value]`:

```
my_dict: dict[int, str] = {
    1: XYZ.SOME_CLASS_CONSTANT
}
```

If you want a dict `int->property of XYZ` specifically, you can make `XYZ` an `Enum`:

```
from enum import Enum


class XYZ(Enum):
    x = '1'
    y = '2'
    z = '3'


d: dict[int, XYZ] = {}

d[1] = XYZ.x   # ok
d[1] = 'what'  # not ok
```

Comment: Sry about that, I used the square brackets in the code, but typoed them in the question. I've corrected the question now.

Comment: This doesn't answer the (original) question, as any IDE worth using would flag `dict{int, str}` as a syntax error, rather than not complaining about anything.